# post-new.php?post_type=product is not loading properly

Tags: wp-admin

Background: I have installed Jigoshop along with my custom theme. When I go to 'Add product' there is no featured image box showing. So I've added the code

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

To functions.php, but the problem is still not resolved.

Inspecting `post-new.php?post_type=product` brings up 3 errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null post-new.php:1112
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker' write-panels.js:119
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'select2' post-new.php:736
```

Also, the admin menus on the left of the page don't show any sub-menus, and when I click screen options it won't open.

I need some help in working out what is happening to cause those errors and I think that is what is causing a knock on effect to prevent featured images displaying on my admin page.

Your help/advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you isolated the issue to Jigoshop alone (without any other plugins)? Had you tried contacting its developers about the issue?